# Why can't I use "Despite" even if it's a noun phrase?

Tags: prepositions

According to my Cambridge preparation Test:

> WRONG:
> I was lucky enough to fulfill an ambition and visit the Galapagos Islands two years ago. **DESPITE** no substitute for a visit, this superbly attractive book provides a fascinating commentary and scientific background to the Galapagos experience.

> RIGHT:
> I was lucky enough to fulfill an ambition and visit the Galapagos Islands two years ago. **WHILE** no substitute for a visit, this superbly attractive book provides a fascinating commentary and scientific background to the Galapagos experience.

I read that DESPITE is a preposition, but I don't understand why it's not suitable for this sentence.

Comment: You would have to say 'Despite _the fact that it is_ no substitute for a visit'.

Comment: You could also say "Despite being no substitute for a visit..."

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't grammatical. The word "despite" has the wrong connotation here.

> de•spite, preposition: despite
>
> without being affected by; in spite of.
> "*he remains a great leader despite age and infirmity*"

(https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en/)

The book is not "in spite of" no substitute for a visit.

In this sentence "while" or "although" conveys the meaning.

Comment: The problem isn't the connotation; it would be appropriate to say "Despite **being** no substitute for a visit".

Comment: @MiloP You're right. I will fix the answer (but not tonight).

Answer (score 3):

Try rewriting the sentences slightly to test the two prepositions:

**While this superbly attractive book is no substitute for a visit, it provides...**

and

**Despite (in spite of) this superbly attractive book is no substitute for a visit, it provides...**

It should be obvious immediately that **despite** doesn't work here. Other possibilities that would work are the subordinating conjunctions, **though** and **although**.